# Possible exceptions when making a callout in Apex

Tags: apex, httprequest

I have inherited the following code and I am wondering if the `try-catch` is actually worth it? (`Logger` is a custom logging class and uses platform events to trigger the log)

```
try {
    response = h.send(req);
} catch(Exception e){
    Logger.log(e);
    throw e;
}
```

What possible exceptions could be thrown here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In isolation, catching the general exception class is usually a red flag.
Catch and re-throw is usually an even bigger red flag.

Any logging would be rolled back (unless it publishes a platform event).

So without additional context, that seems like poorly made code and the try/catch/logging should be removed.

The possible exceptions that I know of for a callout are:

- callout times out (catchable)
- callout tries to go to a domain not in remote site settings (catchable)
- callout in a trigger context (catchable)
- exceeding the callout governor limit (not catchable)
- exceeding 120 seconds for all callouts in a given transaction (not catchable)

Comment: one could imagine retry logic (especially for time out) , perhaps by writing a deadletter object that some async process uses to retry. Now whether that is done in the OP class or in some higher level class is another matter, depending on app design.

Comment: Don't forget about max response size across all callouts.